# Error: read ECONNRESET occurs on ionic serve for newly created apps

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, hybrid-mobile-app

I have just created an ionic 3 app. When I execute `ionic serve`, it runs successfully but when I change something on any file on the project like I changed the text "Welcome to Ionic", the `serve` breaks and throw following error.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

my ionic details are

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\Imdad Turi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0

global packages:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.5
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3
Node              : v6.9.1
npm               : 4.6.1
OS                : Windows 8.1

Environment Variables:

ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\Public

Misc:

backend : pro
```

[image]

Anyone, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This bug is caused by latest ionic-app-script package using ws v3.3.3 as dependencies.

Solution that worked for me:
Remove ./node_modules/ws folder and run

```
npm install ws@3.3.2
```

If this does not work, try upgrading ionic/app-scripts to version 3.1.6.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts/issues/1345

Answer (score 5):

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@3.1.6 --save-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by using, I faced this issue in MAC dring IONIC app development
`npm install ws@3.3.2 --save-dev --save-exact` 
This will work surely :)